# What are the different keyboard types in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have seen these:

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
```

Are there more? What are they and what specifically do they display differently than the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an entire list with descriptions on the [Android InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) documentation page.

*PS - It is the first search result when you google 'android inputtype'.*